# Boost.flyweight and Boost.MPL

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-mpl

I have a question regarding flyweight options, given the definition below, based on http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/flyweight/test/test_basic.cpp

```
typedef boost::flyweights::flyweight<
    std::string, 
    boost::flyweights::tag<int>,
    boost::flyweights::static_holder_class<boost::mpl::_1>,          
    boost::flyweights::hashed_factory_class<
        boost::mpl::_1, 
        boost::mpl::_2, 
        boost::hash<boost::mpl::_2>,
        std::equal_to<boost::mpl::_2>,
        std::allocator<boost::mpl::_1>
    >,
    boost::flyweights::simple_locking,
    boost::flyweights::refcounted
> StringFlyweight;

StringFlyweight    test1("Hello World");
```

what value has `boost::mpl::_1` and `boost::mpl::_2` ? When are asigned ?

`boost::mpl::_1` is most probably `std::string`. `boost::mpl::_2` should be `size_t` ? If true, how is deducted ?
I don't understand how is key_type chosen.

I have read http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/flyweight/doc/tutorial/lambda_expressions.html but I it is my first contact with Boost.MPL and is not enough :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`boost::mpl::_1` and `boost::mpl::_2` are placeholders; they can be used as template parameters to differ the binding to an actual argument to a later time. With this, you can do partial application (transforming a metafunction having an n-arity to a function having a (n-m)-arity), lambda expressions (creating a metafunction on-the-fly where it is needed), etc.

An expression containing at least a placeholder is a placeholder expression, which can be invoked like any other metafunction, with some arguments that will replace the placeholders.

In your example, assuming the following typedef

```
typedef boost::flyweights::hashed_factory_class<
    boost::mpl::_1, 
    boost::mpl::_2, 
    boost::hash<boost::mpl::_2>,
    std::equal_to<boost::mpl::_2>,
    std::allocator<boost::mpl::_1>
> hashed_factory;
```

we can assume that at some other point in the code, the `hashed_factory` will be invoked with some parameter:

```
typedef typename
    boost::mpl::apply<
       hashed_factory,
       X,
       Y
    >::type result; // invoke hashed_factory with X and Y
                    // _1 is "replaced" by X, _2 by Y
```

I did not look in Flyweight code, but we can suppose that `_1` will be bound to the value type of the flyweight, and `_2` to the key type (since it is used for hashing and testing equality). In this case, I think both will be `std::string` since no key type is specified.

I'm not sure my explanation about MPL's placeholders is quite clear, feel free to read the [excellent MPL tutorial](http://www.boost.org/libs/mpl/doc/tutorial/tutorial-metafunctions.html) that explains very well metafunctions, lambda expressions and other template metaprogramming features.

Comment: so, key_type is determined by flyweight. But how can I determine the type and eventually set one ? It's very important that the key is a integral type, not a string.

Comment: If you want to specify the key used to retrieve objects, you need to use `key_value<Key, Value>` as argument to `flyweight<T>`. You also need to tell the library how to retrieve a key from a value, using a "key extractor", a functor that returns the key corresponding to the value given as argument. See [the Boost.Flyweight tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/flyweight/doc/tutorial/key_value.html) for an example.